# Render both layout and page twig file

Tags: php, twig, templating-engine

index.php

```
    ob_start();
    require_once 'page.twig';
    $page = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    ob_start();
    require_once 'base.twig';
    $base = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Array(array(
        'page'  => $page,
        'base' => $base,
    ));
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);


    echo $twig->render('base', $mydataarr);
    echo $twig->render('page', $mydataarr);
```

base.twig

```
These words on the content area<br>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}<br>
These words under the content area<br>
```

page.twig

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}
{% block content %}
These words inside the content area
{% endblock %}
```

PROBLEM:

The problem with the extends keyword. I can print page or base content seperate. But I cannot print them using extends or include or embed.

I'm using a custom made php system. I wrap code into try block and my exception is;

private 'rawMessage' (Twig_Error) => string 'Template "base.twig" is not defined.' (length=32)

Comment: Where is `$mydataarr`defined?...

Comment: it is defined. I do not include it for simpler code

Comment: Why don't you just configure twig to read out your views from a predefined folder?

Comment: @DarkBee A little late, but I am facing the same problem. How/where can I set the predefined folder without using Twig_Loader_Filesystem?

Comment: If you don't use the `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` which loader do you use?

Comment: I use `Twig_Loader_Array`, but inside the template (as string) there is an `extends "base.twig"`. But this extended Template cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late here, but you should name it "base.twig", because this is the extended template in page.twig.

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Array(array(
    'page'  => $page,
    'base.twig' => $base,
));
```